# Output only Unique Rows for given Timerange

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I wanna have all `CHARGE` where the `HPDATUM` to the next is more than 1 year ago.

Current query looks like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT CHARGE, HPDATUM FROM dbo.table123 WHERE CHARGE = '8811985' GROUP BY CHARGE, HPDATUM`

This is an example query with a where restriction to the `CHARGE` which will be gone in the final query to get all `CHARGE`.

This is an example output of the query above:

```
CHARGE  HPDATUM

8811985  1999-10-08  | NEW ENTRY
8811985  2003-06-25  | NEW ENTRY
8811985  2003-06-26  | DUPLICATE TO THE ONE ABOVE
8811985  2004-09-04  | NEW ENTRY
8811985  2004-09-05  | DUPLICATE TO THE ONE ABOVE
8811985  2005-01-09  | DUPLICATE TOO
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Squirrel In the list above the ones where NEW ENTRY is marked by me manually

Comment: that list cannot be the output of the query. In the query you have `DISTINCT CHARGE, HPDATUM` but in the output list, you have duplicate `HPDATUM` of `2003-06-25`

Comment: @Squirrel Sorry its actually the `2003-06-26` on the duplicate row just misstyped it in here i fix it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `LEAD/LAG` here to compare the current `HPDATUM` date against the ones that come before/next in the sequence, for each charge group.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CHARGE, HPDATUM,
        LAG(HPDATUM, 1, DATEADD(year, -1, HPDATUM)) OVER (PARTITION BY CHARGE ORDER BY HPDATUM) HPDATUM_PREV,
        LEAD(HPDATUM, 1, DATEADD(year, 1, HPDATUM)) OVER (PARTITION BY CHARGE ORDER BY HPDATUM) HPDATUM_NEXT
    FROM dbo.table123
)

SELECT CHARGE, HPDATUM
FROM cte
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(year, HPDATUM, HPDATUM_PREV) >= 1 AND
    DATEDIFF(year, HPDATUM, HPDATUM_NEXT) >= 1;
```

If you only want to check in one direction, then remove one of the two lead/lag checks.  Also, if you only want to see a single charge, then add a `WHERE` clause to the CTE.

Comment: Hey your edited version brings me wrong syntax near "LEAD"

Comment: @Badgy Missing comma, sorry.  I did not test my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your Version without the Prev Date also worked well already, may I ask why you decided to go for Prev Date too?

Comment: @Badgy Good question, and you are the one who needs to answer that.  The above answer checks on either side of each record for a given charge that there are no adjacent records within one year.  If you want, you could also just check in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

use window function LAG () to get previous row value of HPDATUM and compare

```
CTE AS
(
    SELECT  t.CHARGE, t.HPDATUM,
            PREV_HPDATUM = LAG (t.HPDATUM) OVER (ORDER BY HPDATUM)
    FROM    dbo.table123 t
    WHERE   t.CHARGE = '8811985'
)
SELECT  CHARGE, HPDATUM
FROM    CTE
WHERE   PREV_HPDATUM    IS NULL
OR      HPDATUM     > DATEADD(YEAR, 1, PREV_HPDATUM)
```